# Boot CRUD Application with Thymeleaf: accept video types

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app. with this thymelaf template in order to accept all video types

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body class="public app app-embed" onorientationchange="window.scrollTo(0, 1)">

<div id="form-embed">

    <div id="messages"></div>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/adduser.html}" th:object="${user}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!-- File -->
        <div class="form-group textogbcn">
            <label  for="video">Video</label>
            <input type="file" id="video"  name="files" accept="video/*">
        </div>



    </form>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

but it seems that only MP4 is accepted, but not mkv,

Testing with `Chrome v87.0.4280.88 (Build oficial) (x86_64)`

Comment: Can you share/Demo your project on JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Accept attribute seems fine. it should be accepting all video. can you check your browser once like is it not updated or it support html 5 tags etc. request to check browser compatibility

Comment: Do share the browser and its version you are using for testing. Nothing related to tags stacks. its only related to HTML 5 Input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution as a workaround.

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*,.mkv">
```

Explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455137/6572971